# Problems with web.py and webopenid

Tags: python, openid, web.py

I'm having a problem with the webopenid module for an application I'm working on.

The code thus far is:

```
import web

from web import template, webopenid
from cms import database

urls = (
    "/", "index",
    "/openid", "webopenid.host"
)

render = template.render("templates", base="base")

class index():
    def GET(self):
        oid = webopenid.status()

        if not oid:
            form = webopenid.form("/openid")
            return render.account_login(form)
        else:
            return render.account_home

app = web.application(urls, globals())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

When I try to submit a login (in the form of: https://openid.domain.com/user), I'm presented with this:

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> at /openid
need more than 1 value to unpack

Python  /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/web.py-0.36-py2.6.egg/web/application.py in _match, line 415
Web POST http://account.dev.s92.org:8080/openid
```

I've checked against other examples of webopenid usage, which indicates that my code is just fine - any ideas what the problem may be?